# Selecting a value within mat-select causes error trying to 'diff'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I've got a `mat-select` element within my component which I have populated with data from my `mongoDB`. Displaying the data as `mat-options` were no problem to me but an error pops up whenever I try to click on an option.

This is the error message that I get whenever I click on an option from the mat-select: `Error trying to diff 'isaac'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`.

Currently, this is what I have:

**`//component.html`**

```
<mat-select formControlName="eighteenthCtrl" required (selectionChange)="selected9($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let agent of agents" [value]="agent.name">
    {{agent.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**`//component.ts`**

```
agents: any = [];

ngOnInit() {

  this.seventhFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    eighteenthCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  this.usersService.getAllAgents().subscribe(agents => {
    this.agents = agents;
    console.log(agents);
  });

}

selected9(event: MatSelectChange) {
  const selectedData9 = {
    value: event.source.value
  };
  this.agents = selectedData9.value;
  console.log(selectedData9);
}
```

Why does it still give me this error even though I've provided an array? Moreover, `console.log(agents)` correctly displays the array and its objects. What have I missed out?

Comment: Try this .agents.push(agents);

Comment: Could you help me specify clearer which code you'd like me to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selected9(event: MatSelectChange) {
    const selectedData9 = {
      value: event.source.value
    };
    this.agents = selectedData9.value; // <- the problem is here
    console.log(selectedData9)
  }
```

It seems the problem is here. When you select one, you set the `agents` with its value which is `string` or something else which is not an array.

You can save it in other property. For example:

```
selected: string;
...
selected9(event: MatSelectChange) {
    const selectedData9 = {
      value: event.source.value
    };
    this.selected = selectedData9.value;
    console.log(selectedData9)
}
```

Comment: could you suggest a workaround? Because at the end of the day I would still want to capture the value of the MatSelectChange and save it in the database.

Comment: updated, it's simple :) you can just save it in other variable

Comment: Thank you very much, I've accepted your answer. Sometimes, a pair of fresh eyes help alot!